# How can I upload Photo to 「Build > Photo」using by APS API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

I want to upload photo(.png) using by APS API.
But I can't find ways.

I checked this site, and checked references of Autodesk sites.
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/autodesk-build-photos-api
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/photos-getphoto-GET/

Is there still only read-only?
I would be grateful if you could tell me.
Thank you for reading this far.